# Creating a custom DKIM (Domain Authentication) in DNS settings

Tags: dns, dkim

I'm trying to do the following as told by MailChimp:

1. Set a TXT (SPF) record for lakesentrancesurflifesaving.org.au to:

> v=spf1 include:servers.mcsv.net ?all

2. Set the CNAME record for *k1._domainkey.lakesentrancesurflifesaving.org.au* to:

> dkim.mcsv.net

---

What I have added to my DNS using DirectAdmin as seen below in the screen shot and text, some values I have hidden:

> k1._domainkey.lakesentrancesurflifesaving.org.au  CNAME   dkim.mcsv.net
>   lakesentrancesurflifesaving.org.au.   TXT v=spf1
>   include:servers.mcsv.net ?all

[image]

For some reason MailChimp says it does not detect the right values, I have waited 48 hours with no luck. After some research I know that a 'period' (.) can have a significant effect. So I would like to double check what I have against what i have been told to do by MailChimp.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there should be double quotes around your TXT entry, just like for that other TXT entry you have shown.

As far as I can state, this double quotes normally happen automatically (my provider), but maybe check with your own provider.

See how nslookup resolves the two entries differently
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I have included brackets and waited 24 hours and doesn't seem to have made a difference. It is possible that mailchimp only tells me when its not working, not how many errors, it is quite possible I have more than one error, and well now I have one less with your correction.

Comment: To add, I did change the CNAME to both end with a period (.) which now works. I don't think i needed to wait as the name servers are on the domain too. Thanks for your help as no doubt you fixed one of the errors.

Comment: TXT entry seems to resolve correct now. CNAME entry still does not resolve to dkim.mcsv.net on my side.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 SPF records.

Multiple SPF records are not recommended and may cause delivery and spam classification issues. Combine the 2 records into one record.

Here is one of many tools you can use:  http://www.spfwizard.net/